Where does the $\pi^2$ term come from in this Feynman diagram?
I am looking at this paper on anomalous magnetic moment. Trying to go through the calculations. The first graph 1a  on p. 1070 seems to be the "easiest" as it requires no renormalization and has no divergences unlike the others.
It shows how the integral can be decomposed into integrals of type $M(a,b,c,d,e)$ and $N(a,b,c,d,e)$ where $a,b,c,d,e$ are integers. (It doesn't state whether the $M$ and $N$ integrals themselves need to be convergent.)
Through various linear relations these can be decomposed still into those of type $$N(1,1,1,1,1) = I(0)$$ and specific values of $M$ which are given as ratios of gamma functions which should always be rational numbers.
The value of the graph 1a is given in Table II on p. 1072 as:
$$\frac{1}{6} -\frac{5}{6} I(0) + \frac{13}{36}\pi^2.$$
Thus I'm confused as to how the term $\frac{13}{36}\pi^2$ can appear? As from the relations the integral should only contain rational numbers and $I(0)$. Even taking into account the we need to take a limit at the end as the photon propagator momentum, $q^2$, goes to 0, I can't see how this term emerges. Any clues?
I have so far managed to calculate the 0-loop $(=0)$ and 1-loop $(=1/2)$ integrals successfully by using this introduction and using FORM to simplify the gamma matrices. But these 2-loop integrals are a lot harder. The Feynman parameterisation method is not much use as it just produces further integrals which are hard to solve. So the above method of linear relations seems the best method. So far, I can't even understand the form of the answer.
(BTW, yes I could probably just use some software to solve it all for me but I'm trying to learn the details).
Also I can see from the other graphs how the term $\frac{1}{\epsilon}-\gamma$ appears since this is the approximation of $\Gamma(\epsilon)$ when $\epsilon$ is small so it's just this $\pi^2$ term that is a mystery. (I guess it might come from dimensional regularisation with $d=4+\epsilon$ and  as $$\Gamma(\epsilon) = \frac{1}{\epsilon} -\gamma + \epsilon (6\gamma^2+\pi^2)/12 + ...$$ and somehow the other terms cancel leaving just the $\pi^2$ term. (But then somehow all the $\gamma^n$ terms would have to miraculously cancel which seems unlikely).

Why do you believe the answer has to be rational?

@Triatticus No I said the answer should be a combination of rational numbers and I(0) since the paper says it is a linear combination of the integrals M and N. But I am perhaps neglecting that we take the dimension to be $4+\epsilon$.
